# HMCharacteristicWriteAction what to pass for targetValue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8, homekit

In HomeKit My code is

```
HMAction *myAction = [[HMCharacteristicWriteAction alloc] 
initWithCharacteristic:[[lightBulbService characteristics] objectAtIndex:0] targetValue:characteristicValue];
```

HMCharacteristicWriteAction have method initWithCharacterstic which requried two parameter

1) For initWithCharacteristic need to pass, HMService object.

2) For targetValue, What i need to Pass for targetValue ?

i need to know what is,  target value for the characteristic ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The target value depends on the characteristic you are writing.  A lightbulb may support characteristics such as

- `HMCharacteristicTypeHue` - Integer 0-360 (degrees)
- `HMCharacteristicTypeSaturation` - Integer 0 - 100 (percentage)
- `HMCharacteristicTypeBrightness` - Integer 0 - 100 (percentage).
- `HMCharacteristicTypePowerState` - Boolean on or off.

You can pretty much guarantee that a lightbulb will support `HMCharacteristicTypePowerState`.  The others maybe not.  A lightbulb can also support additional characteristics, defined by the manufacturer - A strobe might support a 'blink rate' characteristic for example.

Comment: if i need to set blub state off what should i do ?

Comment: Write `NO`/`false` to `HMCharacteristicTypePowerState`

Comment: Hue and Saturation are Floats. Brightness is Integer. If you attempt to pass a float to brightness, you'll get an "Invalid argument" error.